# XFCE Desktop - Rocketchat Doesn't Show In Notification Tray

Tags: xfce, system-tray

I recently installed the XFCE desktop environment and switched to it from my Ubuntu 18.04 Mate Desktop installation.

I have the [Rocketchat](https://rocket.chat/) application installed which will "close to tray" as it were. Whilst application like shutter will appear in the notification tray, Rocketchat doesn't appear there. Is there a package I need to install?

Comment: Thanks, thats what I needed to know. I had to run `sudo apt-get install xfce4-indicator-plugin` and then add the "Indicator Plugin" to the panel. This showed rocketchat. If you put your comment with this info as the answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exist three panel-plugins in xfce4 which have almost the same meaning:

- `Status Notifier Plugin` from the package `xfce4-statusnotifier-plugin`
- `Indicator Plugin` from the package `xfce4-indicator-plugin`
- `Notification Area` which is part of the package `xfce4-panel`

Normally we will have only one of these plugins added to our panel, but some applications will appear in only one of these plugins, so you'll have to try which one of them is used by `Rocketchat` by adding the currently not used plugins to your panel.