# Diodon not showing in Xubuntu task bar

Tags: xubuntu, taskbar, xfce-panel

I installed [Diodon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/diodon.1.html) on my Xubuntu 18.04 using

```
sudo apt install diodon
```

Although Diodon does run (if I open the whisker menu and open Diodon I do see the clipboard menu), the icon does not appear on the taskbar.

As a plugin I do have application indicator checked.

I found a partial solution by creating a keyboard shortcut to launch Diodon (and show the menu), but I would also like to open the menu from the taskbar icon.

I did try right-clicking on the taskbar (or panel?), then "Add New Items" but I did not find Diodon there.

How might I resolve getting Diodon on the taskbar?

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1173449/590937) might be helpful.

Comment: To go along with @mook765 comment there, it appears as though diodon appears in the Status Notifier Plugin.

Comment: It did not appear when I added Status plugin and Indicator plugin (now some icons appear twice and I can't remove the duplicates). Notification appears greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1173449/590937). I tweaked several things before realizing the the problem had been fixed (somehow I missed the icon when it really appeared) so I'm not exactly sure which of the 3 options fixed it. But something fixed it! thanks to @mook765 and @Terrance.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this situation some days before, what i did is -

1. First uninstall/remove Diodon.
2. Install it using '**Ubuntu Software**'.
3. Launch Diodon, check it's showing on taskbar or not.

If not:

1. Just click on **Launch** again then select **Quit**.
2. Launch again, solved!

This worked for me, you can try too!